# Verbalize person age in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to verbalize the age of a person. Is there a Rails helper for that:

For example:

- If the person is less than one month: X days old
- If the person is less than one year:  X months old
- If it has between 1 and 5: X Years, Y months old

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could customize the helper in the ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper module.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4b1985578a2b27b170358e82e72e00d23fdaf087/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L67

Other than than that, you can create your own helper pretty easily, without taking into account leap days... which may or may not be important.

```
def humanize_age(person)
  age = Date.today - person.birth_date
  years = (age / 1.year).to_i
  age = age % 1.year
  months = (age / 1.month).to_i
  age = age % 1.month
  days = (age / 1.day).to_i

  if years < 1
    if months < 1
      "#{days} days old"
    else
      "#{months} months old"
    end
  else
    "#{years} years, #{months} months old"
  end
end
```

This could be cleaned up a bit, and I haven't tested it, but this should work.